# How can I add the second string of an array to the first string of the same array, ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of cities and states. Looks something like this:

```
locations = ["Colorado Springs","CO","Denver","CO","Kissimmee","FL","Orlando", "FL"]
```

I would ultimately like to get this result:

```
locations = ["Colorado Springs, CO","CO","Denver, CO","CO","Kissimmee, FL","FL","Orlando, FL", "FL"]
```

I did this to test:

```
locations[0] << ", #{locations[1]}"
```

And got this as a result:

```
locations = ["Colorado Springs, CO", "CO", "Denver", "CO", "Kissimmee", "FL", "Orlando", "FL"]
```

I am attempting the code below to convert the rest of the array but getting `nil` as a response:

```
locations = ["Colorado Springs","CO","Denver","CO","Kissimmee","FL","Orlando", "FL"]

counter0 = 0
counter1 = 1 

while counter0 < locations.length
  locations[counter0] << locations[counter1]
  counter0 += 2 
  counter1 += 2
end 

=> nil
```

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer? No less, an answer that is incorrect. As I write this, you've change your selection to another incorrect answer. Look at the return values both give. They are not what you said you wanted in the question. Do not change your question! I suggest you retract the greenie and wait a couple of hours for the dust to clear, then make a selection. There is no rush to make a selection. Consider also that some readers may still be working on answers and others may not bother giving an answer because you've already made a selection.

Comment: It is tricky to change the length of an array while iterating through it. You better avoid it.

Comment: @sawa: Actually, the length of the array doesn't change. Only items within the array are modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
locations.each_slice(2).flat_map { |city, state| ["#{city}, #{state}", state] }
  #=> ["Colorado Springs, CO", "CO", "Denver, CO", "CO",
  #    "Kissimmee, FL", "FL", "Orlando, FL", "FL"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use `flat_map`.

```
locations.each_slice(2).flat_map{|x, y| [[x, y].join(", "), y]}
# => ["Colorado Springs, CO", "CO", "Denver, CO", "CO", "Kissimmee, FL", "FL", "Orlando, FL", "FL"]
```

Comment: You beat me by 14 seconds. Can we call it a tie?

Comment: Yeah. I thought so. Plus, there is a minor difference.

Comment: I find it a bit scary. Just the other day my wife said she thought I was becoming less forgiving of other's mistakes and at times was downright rude.

Comment: I hope I haven't influenced you in a bad way. But, caring about the details is a good thing.